# When and why should a destructor be declared as virtual?

Tags: c++

As in

```
class TestA
{
     TestA();
     virtual ~TestA(); 
}
```

So why and when should the destructor for TestA be virtual??

Comment: Also see: **[When to use virtual destructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/439793)** and **[When should my destructor be virtual?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-dtors)**

Answer (score 15):

Any class that has any virtual methods should have a virtual destructor.  Otherwise, the superclass's destructor will not be called if the object is deleted through a pointer to the child class.

In other words, if the keyword `virtual` exists in the class declaration, you must at least have this:

```
virtual ~Class() {};
```

In theory, you don't need to do this if you never delete a child object through a pointer to a base class, but in practice, it is far safer to do this at the outset regardless of how the class is used, as not doing so has no real benefit.

Comment: As an aside, if the class inherits from a class with virtual dtor, there's no need to restate it. Also, look into explicitly defaulting with `= default;`.

Comment: I think you mean "if you never delete an instance of the child class through a pointer to the base class"

Comment: Yes, you correct, edited.

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply to `shared_ptr<T>`… the correct destructor will be called even if `T` is a base class without a virtual destructor, as long as you construct the first `shared_ptr` correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on your class only being used in a certain way, though.  The class can't require it only be used with `shared_ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor should be declared virtual if inheritance is involved and the derived class needs to be destroyed in a specific way that differs from the base class.

Comment: Already 3 upvotes for an answer that imo doesn't quite cut it? Suggested reading (as linked by Snowman already) for a less vague description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors